# How to combine three date columns in a data frame into a single variable?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks a bit like this:

```
   Type   Size `Jul-17` `Aug-17` `Sep-17`
1     A  Large       35       24       80
2     B Medium       81       13       38
3     C  Small       30       64       45
4     D  Large       97       68       65
5     E Medium       31       69       33
6     F  Small       84       74       12
```

I use the ddply function a lot, and instead of summing the three columns together like below...

```
result <- ddply(Example, .(Type), (summarize),
                Q3sum = sum(`Jul-17`, `Aug-17`, `Sep-17`))
```

I'd like to be able to reference a single variable that contains those three columns and call it "Q3". Is there a way to do this that will still allow the data to work with ddply? I've tried setting the three columns to a single variable using `` Q3<- c(`Jul-17`, `Aug-17`, `Sep-17`) ``, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would your expected outcome look like?

Comment: Instead of referencing the three columns in ddply, I would reference a single variable within ddply that would work instead.

Comment: So instead of `Jul-17`, `Aug-17`, `Sep-17` it would be simply "Q3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducible data frame:

```
read.table(check.names = FALSE, text="Type   Size Jul-17 Aug-17 Sep-17
A  Large       35       24       80
B Medium       81       13       38
C  Small       30       64       45
D  Large       97       68       65
E Medium       31       69       33
F  Small       84       74       12", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> xdf

xdf
##   Type   Size Jul-17 Aug-17 Sep-17
## 1    A  Large     35     24     80
## 2    B Medium     81     13     38
## 3    C  Small     30     64     45
## 4    D  Large     97     68     65
## 5    E Medium     31     69     33
## 6    F  Small     84     74     12
```

If you just want the sum of the columns into one `Q3` column:

```
xdf$Q3 <- rowSums(xdf[,3:5])

xdf
##   Type   Size Jul-17 Aug-17 Sep-17  Q3
## 1    A  Large     35     24     80 139
## 2    B Medium     81     13     38 132
## 3    C  Small     30     64     45 139
## 4    D  Large     97     68     65 230
## 5    E Medium     31     69     33 133
## 6    F  Small     84     74     12 170
```

If you want the 3 months making up "Q3" nested into one column:

```
xdf$q3_alt <- apply(xdf, 1, function(x) { list(as.numeric(x[3:5])) })

xdf
##   Type   Size Jul-17 Aug-17 Sep-17  Q3     q3_alt
## 1    A  Large     35     24     80 139 35, 24, 80
## 2    B Medium     81     13     38 132 81, 13, 38
## 3    C  Small     30     64     45 139 30, 64, 45
## 4    D  Large     97     68     65 230 97, 68, 65
## 5    E Medium     31     69     33 133 31, 69, 33
## 6    F  Small     84     74     12 170 84, 74, 12

str(xdf)
## 'data.frame':    6 obs. of  7 variables:
##  $ Type  : chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
##  $ Size  : chr  "Large" "Medium" "Small" "Large" ...
##  $ Jul-17: int  35 81 30 97 31 84
##  $ Aug-17: int  24 13 64 68 69 74
##  $ Sep-17: int  80 38 45 65 33 12
##  $ Q3    : num  139 132 139 230 133 170
##  $ q3_alt:List of 6
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ : num  35 24 80
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ : num  81 13 38
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ : num  30 64 45
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ : num  97 68 65
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ : num  31 69 33
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ : num  84 74 12
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot. The solution was a lot more straightforward than I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is the gather function from tidyr. If you use dplyr you can make it in one line of code.

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> df%>%
+   gather(key = Q3,value = values,Jul_17:Sep_17)
   type     size     Q3 values
1     1 A  Large Jul_17     35
2     2 B Medium Jul_17     81
3     3 C  Small Jul_17     30
4     4 D  Large Jul_17     97
5     5 E Medium Jul_17     31
6     6 F  Small Jul_17     84
7     1 A  Large Aug_17     24
8     2 B Medium Aug_17     13
9     3 C  Small Aug_17     64
10    4 D  Large Aug_17     68
11    5 E Medium Aug_17     69
12    6 F  Small Aug_17     74
13    1 A  Large Sep_17     80
14    2 B Medium Sep_17     38
15    3 C  Small Sep_17     45
16    4 D  Large Sep_17     65
17    5 E Medium Sep_17     33
18    6 F  Small Sep_17     12
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want something along the lines of [melt](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/reshape2/versions/1.4.2/topics/melt) from the reshape2 package or [gather](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.7.1/topics/gather) from the tidyr packge. They will make your `data.frame` longer with all the `Jul-17`, `Aug-17`, and `Sep-17` values in one column and another column declaring which month each data point came from.

Check out this [nice primer](http://garrettgman.github.io/tidying/) on data tidying.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you!